# Wait fragment to be attach

Tags: android, error-handling, android-asynctask

I have an app where I use couple fragments. On my testing devices the code work perfect. But on crashlytics I see that on some devices my app crash when try to run an AsyncTask on a fragment.
Error message told that "Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException
Fragment ActivityPoI{51ba000} (078ad72b-5fa8-49c3-9f38-0c15addda8d1)} not attached to a context."

To avoid that I plan to use next code. I want that asyncTask to start just after what fragment was attached.

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    while (true) {
        if (isAdded()) {
            new SyncGetLocations(this).execute();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Do you believe that I have choiced the right solution?

Comment: it rather means that fragment is no longer attached  ... just check inside `SyncGetLocations.onPostExecute` if fragment is still attached

Comment: If just check if is attached the asynctask can not start. I need to wait untill I am sure that fragment was attached.

Comment: fragment is attached before onViewCreated ... it's attached in right before onAttach ... check fragment's lifecycle

Comment: I call my asyncTask in onCreateView. So I think that each time I call asyncTask my fragment is already attached. But I saw on crashlytics that on some devices return next error "Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException Fragment ActivityPoI{51ba000} (078ad72b-5fa8-49c3-9f38-0c15addda8d1)} not attached to a context."

Comment: Again ... error is rather from onPostExecute and it rather means that fragment is no longer attached (fx you click back button before onPostExecute was called)